# Error:There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, webforms

I'm having a problem while setting many commands on the same opened Connection, it always says that there is a DataReader associated with the command which must be closed, although I closed it it still give me the Same problem, this is my Code:

```
 protected void Afficher_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Consommation where idAbonnement = @ab and periode between @d1 and @d2 ",con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ab", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", TextBox2.Text);
            con.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            //cmd.ExecuteReader().Close();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select SUM(Qte) from Consommation where idAbonnement =" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue, con);
            Label2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select AVG(Qte) from Consommation where idAbonnement =" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue, con);
            Label4.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
```

Can you please explain to me what's the problem exactly and how to fix it?
Thanks previously.

Comment: In accordance with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx it says that "Note that while a DataReader is open, the Connection is in use exclusively by that DataReader. You cannot execute any commands for the Connection, including creating another DataReader, until the original DataReader is closed."  so, you need to close the reader - eg your commented out line

Comment: @BugFinder I tried and closed the Reader, it kept giving the same error, that's why I commented it.

Comment: Which line is actually giving the error the second sql statement or the 3rd? if you kept the close in, it would probably change to the 3rd Im guessing

Comment: At first It gives the exception on this line  "GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();" then when I tried and closed the reader using : "cmd.ExecuteReader().Close();" It gives the exception on this one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Solution I've tried and it Worked perfectly, based on the post here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/08/20/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-closed-first-explained/

```
            using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = rd;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should close the `SqlDataReader`. The best way in this case was to use:

```
GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

or use a different approach, for example with a `SqlDataAdapter` and a `DataTable`:

```
string sql = "select * from Consommation " +
             "where idAbonnement = @ab " +
             "and periode between @d1 and @d2 ";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
{
    con.Open();
    var cmd = da.SelectCommand;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ab", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", TextBox2.Text);
    DataTable dataSource = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dataSource);
    GridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
    GridView1.DataBind();

   using (var cmdSumQte = new SqlCommand(
        "select SUM(Qte) from Consommation where idAbonnement = @idAbonnement", con))
    {
        cmdSumQte.Parameters.Add("@idAbonnement", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
            int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        Label2.Text = cmdSumQte.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }

    using(var cmdAvgQte = new SqlCommand(
            "select AVG(Qte) from Consommation where idAbonnement = @idAbonnement", con))
    {
        cmdAvgQte.Parameters.Add("@idAbonnement", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
            int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        Label4.Text = cmdAvgQte.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}
```

Note that i've also used parameters for the other commands and also used multiple. On that way you avoid careless mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

try using different name for 2nd command:

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Consommation where idAbonnement = @ab and periode between @d1 and @d2 ",con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ab", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", TextBox2.Text);
            con.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            cmd.Dispose();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select SUM(Qte) from Consommation where idAbonnement =" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue, con);
            Label2.Text = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select AVG(Qte) from Consommation where idAbonnement =" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue, con);
            Label4.Text = cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
```

Also, very important: **USE PARAMETERS, YOU ARE EXPOSED TO SQL INJECTION**

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Afficher_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Consommation where idAbonnement = @ab and periode between @d1 and @d2 ",con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ab", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", TextBox2.Text);
            con.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            GridView1.DataBind();
            cmd.Dispose();
            cmd = null;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select SUM(Qte) from Consommation where idAbonnement =" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue, con);
            Label2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select AVG(Qte) from Consommation where idAbonnement =" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue, con);
            Label4.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using multiple result sets, you need to add the below statement

MultipleActiveResultSets=true;

in your connectionstring.

For ex.,

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=true;

Comment: I tried it but it gives this error: Invalid value for key 'integrated security'. in the Authentication page.(I FOUND THE SOLUTION ANYWAYS THANKS)